# SocketIo implemented in loopback4, how to make it accessible from the client once deployed on AWS?

Tags: angularjs, amazon-web-services, nginx, websocket, loopbackjs

I'm using Loopback4 on the server and Angular for the client. And everything is deployed on AWS.

I need to be able to issue events through a websocket at the end of a cron job in the API to notify the client. I am able to do it now, when my application is running in my local environment everything works correctly. My client receives the messages from the socket but on deployment, it doesn't work. I always got the same errors:

```
//request
Request URL: ws://mydeployurl.elasticbeanstalk.com:3008/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket:

//responses
Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
or
WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
```

Inside my loopback application I have a service that is in charge of creating the websocket and broadcasting the messages. This is the code:

```
import {BindingScope, injectable} from '@loopback/core';

@injectable({scope: BindingScope.SINGLETON})
export class SocketService {
  private socket;

  constructor() {
    const express = require('express');
    const app = express();
    const port = 3008;

    const server = app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`Server connection on port ${port}`); // Server Connnected
    });
    this.socket = require('socket.io')(server);
    this.socket.on('connection', (socket: any) => {
      console.log('Socket: client connected');
    });
  }

  emitTicketUpdated(): void {
    console.log('Socket: emit ticket updated');
    this.socket.emit('tickets-updated');
  }
}
```

After some research I discovered that the problem may be associated with **nginx** blocking the socket connection. But I have tried unsuccessfully to create a configuration file for nginx in my project to allow socket connection.

Acording to [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html) i should create a .conf in a folder called .platform/nginx/conf.d/ to extend nginx config. But i am not sure what to put on that file. I have tried almos everythig without success.

And right now i am not sure if the issue is related with the way i am creating and handleing the websocket or with nginx config or something else.

I have been stuck on this problem for over two days. Any suggestions? thanks in advance.